# Python unittest Mock patch object not methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am having trouble getting my head around unit testing with Mock in Python.  I have a method `start_thing()` in a class I'd like to test:

```
class ComplexClass:
   def __init__(self, lots, of, args):
       self.lots = lots
       ..

   def start_thing(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        print "some error!!"
        assert False
```

The class this belongs to is quite complex and a pain to try and mock manually. That is why I started to look at using Mock.

I would like to setup a mock that Mocks an instance of this class to make it easy to run a unittest, but not mock the method `start_thing()` so that the real `start_thing()` implementation is tested, not a mocked version .. so I created this:

```
class TestComplexClass(TestCase):
     @patch.object(module.ComplexClass, 'start_thing')
     def test_start_thing(self, mock_method):
        ComplexClass.start_thing()
```

When running my test the debug trace, assert or print are not hit in my real method `start_thing()`, which suggests I have mocked the class and the method - where I just want to mock the object and test the real methods. What am I doing wrong here? Is that possible?

I have found lots of examples with Mock showing how to create a mock version of the method I want to test, which I think is kind of pointless since I don't want to check if it's being called correctly, rather I want to test the implementation in the real code, and mock the class it belongs to so it's easier to create.

Perhaps there's something I don't understand about the Mock testing idea as a whole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you want to mock that class but to stub it out, ex:

```
class ComplexClassStub(ComplexClass):
  def __init__(self):
    self.lots = None
    self.the_rest_of_the_args = None # Now your complex class isn't so complex.

class ComplexClassTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def Setup(self):
    self.helper = ComplexClassStub()

  def testStartThing(self):
    with mock.patch.object(self.helper, 'SomethingToMock') as something_mocked:
      expected = 'Fake value'
      actual = self.helper.start_thing()
      self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
      something_mocked.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the help! That isn't so bad. Is this stub  typically created with the tests?
Can you explain the value in testing the way something is called (like with Mock) versus testing the actual body of the real methods etc?

Comment: If you're mocking out something that is important to the functionality of the test, then using assert_called_once_with and/or assert_has_calls, is a way to enforce that what you are mocking is being called exactly how you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much. This made a lot of sense and was very useful. Thanks again!